# Convert monochrom image into x,y coordinates into a dataframe

Tags: r, image, coordinates, monochrome

I want to turn the "black values" of a monochrom image into x-y points to plot them in a scatter plot later.

The following image in the link explains easily what im looking for.

[image]

I also want to control the amount of "points per area"!

Lets take:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tieudesigns.com](http://www.tieudesigns.com/tutorials/tutorial_0001/golf_01.jpg))</sub>

as our example image.

## Edit:

here is what i came up with:

```
> library("magick")
> test <- image_read('*CENSORED*\\white-circle-black-background.jpg')
> testDS <- as.raster(test)
```

Comment: Try this [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/index.html)

Comment: You can try `jpeg` library for file reading and `imagedata` function to get a matrix of pixels.

Comment: i have searched the web for a solution but yet not the desired output.

Comment: How do you want to control the number of points per area?

Comment: You could invert your image and multiply it with noise then alter the threshold on the noise till you have the density of points you seek.

Comment: It's unlikely you "searched the web". You haven't shown you even know how to read images in to R let alone sample points (both of which have clear first-page hits on google). You really should show that you did _something_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just demonstrating what I was alluding to in the comments. You would have to adapt the approach to `R` as I am showing a *technique* using **ImageMagick** at the command line:

```
convert mask.jpg -threshold 50% -colorspace gray -fx "(1-u)*rand()>0.8 ? 0:1" result.png
```

[image]

Or changing the threshold:

```
convert mask.jpg -threshold 50% -colorspace gray -fx "(1-u)*rand()>0.9 ? 0:1" result.png
```

[image]

The interesting part is obviously the `-fx` expression, which uses the value of each pixel - referred to as `u` - and scaled on the range [0,1] where 0 is black and 1 is white. Basically I invert the pixel (`1-u`) and multiply by a random number then threshold it. Changing the threshold changes the density of pixels. Depending on the result, I either output a black or a white pixel.

I am not sure what you mean by *"translate those values into coordinates"*, but if you really want a list of the black pixel coordinates:

```
convert mask.jpg -threshold 50% -colorspace gray -fx "(1-u)*rand()>0.8?0:1" -depth 8 txt: | grep "(0)"
```

**Sample Output**

```
2,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
4,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
6,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
7,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
8,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
10,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
13,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
14,0: (0)  #000000  gray(0)
```

Comment: this is what im aiming for and then transform those values to x,y coordinates. i will try my luck.

Comment: Not sure about your list of coordinates but I have updated my answer with some extra material at the end.